# Are the Walk of Fame costume performers legal?

Tags: united-states, copyright, california

I recently learned that there are many people (arguably "struggling actors" or possibly just homeless) who dress up in costumes around Hollywood Boulevard to take pictures with tourists for tips. For example, [the tragic life of Christopher Dennis](https://deadline.com/2020/01/hollywood-superman-will-be-buried-in-costume-1202779929/) included dressing up as Superman, and there are also many other copyrighted characters owned by DC, Disney, and other major companies.

At first, I assumed that since they were profiting off of copyrighted characters, they would probably be sued out of existence immediately. But then I thought, I'm assuming these people probably purchased the costumes from a company that legitimately licensed the character. If the rights owners are authorizing the sale of these costumes, I don't see how they could possibly object to people buying and wearing them in public. So really that just leaves the question of whether it is legal for them to work for tips while wearing the costumes.

I don't recall ever seeing a costume with a disclaimer that said "Not for commercial purposes," but it still seems like a gray area at best. Are these performers breaking copyright laws?

Comment: Why would anyone sue them? There is no money to made

Comment: @Hilmar because if you don’t defend your trade mark rights you lose them